# Creating a vertical scrolling transition effect in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Wanted to get insight and help advancing a plugin I am beginning to build!

Looking to build the same effect that [AKQA.com](http://www.akqa.com/) has, were on page load certain elements transition into place (using translateY of course). However if the elements are in view within the browser window. As you scroll down, other elements have the same effect transitioning up into place and appearing from opacity 0 to 1.

**What I am trying to accomplish** is getting select elements to  transition from opacity 0 to 1 effect translating upwards via `scroll`only however when the element is not in-view. If however the elements are already in view (due to page loading right where the elements are) the effect will happen automatically until you scroll down to reveal more elements.

Currently in my JS code I am grabbing the data selector on the elements and applying to each of the elements a transition-delay and a CSS class which suppose to be the class that creates the effect. I have three variables docHeight, offSetter and scrolling that are suppose to help me create the logic behind the scrolling effect but I simply can not wrap my head around creating the effect.

Here is a live demo in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coder101/hYS48/1/

**The Hi link is simply for testing to toggle the `in-view` CSS class I have**

Thank you for the help!

**Javascript**

```
  var loop = function ScrollTransition( ) {

        var core = function() {

                var i = 100,
                    dataTheme = $('[data-show*="on-scroll"]').not('in-view'),
                    docHeight = $( document ).height(),
                    offSetter = parseInt(dataTheme.offset().top, 10),
                    scrolling = dataTheme.scrollTop();


                    // console.log(h);


                dataTheme.each(function() {  
                    _this = $( this ),
                    _this.css("transition-delay", i + "ms", i += 100);
                });
            },

            initializer = function() {

                if ( el.hasClass('js') && el.hasClass('no-touch') && el.hasClass('csstransitions') ) {
                    core();

                }
            };

            return {
                init:initializer()
            }
    };

loop();




// For testing
var divElements = $('article');
var doc = $( '#hit' );

doc.on("click", function() {

    if( el.hasClass('js') &&  el.hasClass('no-touch') && el.hasClass('csstransitions') ) {
        divElements.toggleClass('in-view');
    }

});
```

**CSS**

```
.base {
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;

}

article {
  margin-right:45px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}


/*  starting phase */
.js.no-touch.csstransitions [data-show="on-scroll"] {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,90px);
    -ms-transform:translate(0,90px);
    transform:translate(0,90px);


    -webkit-transition:opacity .6s .1s, -webkit-transform .6s ease;
    transition:opacity .6s .1s, transform .6s ease
}



/*  finishing phase */
.js.no-touch.csstransitions .in-view {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform:translate(0,0);
    transform:translate(0,0)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your exact question?

Comment: i suppose that similar plugin you are developing already exist. Take a look [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)